# Cordova App - build tool error - Gradle

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

I have a cordova application. Unable to compile it after a system re-install.

I am having the error - 
`Error:No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.`

My profile has

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/home/iamkhush/Android/Sdk/tools"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="/home/iamkhush/Android/Sdk/platform-tools"
export ANDROID_STUDIO='/home/iamkhush/Downloads/work/android-studio/bin/'
```

I have dirs with names `19.1.0` and `23.0.1` in `home/iamkhush/Android/Sdk/build-tools`

I have gradle 2.7 installed.

[image]

What else should I be looking into to resolve this? I believe I have seen all the posts similar to this, but couldnt get it working.

Comment: Please post the logcat error stack that you see at build time.

Comment: @Ahmed - http://pastebin.com/u2XKb5cM

Comment: Its Working for me check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38660955/ionic-cordova-in-android-studio-no-installed-build-tools-found

Comment: Hey, i know it is an old post. But Did you manage to fix it? I', having the same issue here..

Answer (score 12):

Please, run the following commands.

On Windows:

```
cd c:\Android\android-sdk\tools\bin
```

*Remember to replace tools path according to yours.*

and then:

```
sdkmanager "build-tools;26.0.0"
```

Answer (score 9):

You have set `ANDROID_HOME` incorrect in your `~/.profile`. Point it just to the `SDK` folder.

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/home/iamkhush/Android/Sdk"
```

Also, make sure that `JAVA_HOME`, `PATH` are set correct, and `/home/iamkhush/Android/Sdk` have **Android SDK build-tools** version `19.1.0` or higher.

Answer (score 5):

Setting the environment variable `ANDROID_HOME` to the right directory helped me:
`C:\Users\roelo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\`

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have installed **Android SDK build-tools version 19.1.0** properly.

Open Android SDK and check that.

Comment: I have `build-tools version 19.1.0` and ***JAVA_HOME***  `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91` ***ANDROID_HOME*** `D:\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools`

Answer (score -1):

1. Set environment variable ANDROID_HOME correctly.
2. Set JAVA_HOME variable, also the mandatory changes to PATH variable.
3. Close terminal,open again
4. Remove android platform
5. Add android platform

This was the solution i found.