# Ionic Cordova in Android Studio (no installed build tools found)

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, ionic2

I develop in ionic 2 and I'm trying to open the project (from ionic android build) in Android Studio.

I get the following error:

> Error:No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.

The problem is the Build Tool is already installed:

[image]

I'm using the latest version of **cordova** with **ionic2**.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I installed a new version of Android studio and I only have platform tool 28.0.1, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 15):

You should refer `doFindLatestInstalledBuildTools` method in cordova.gradle file:

```
String doFindLatestInstalledBuildTools(String minBuildToolsVersion) {
    def availableBuildToolsVersions
    try {
        availableBuildToolsVersions = getAvailableBuildTools()
    } catch (e) {
        println "An exception occurred while trying to find the Android build tools."
        throw e
    }
    if (availableBuildToolsVersions.length > 0) {
        def highestBuildToolsVersion = availableBuildToolsVersions[0]
        if (compareVersions(highestBuildToolsVersion, minBuildToolsVersion) < 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                "No usable Android build tools found. Highest installed version is " +
            highestBuildToolsVersion + "; minimum version required is " +
            minBuildToolsVersion + ".")
        }
        highestBuildToolsVersion
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(
        "No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version " +
            minBuildToolsVersion + " or higher.")
    }
}
```

Obviosly, `getAvailableBuildTools()` returns empty array:

```
String[] getAvailableBuildTools() {
    def buildToolsDir = new File(getAndroidSdkDir(), "build-tools")
    buildToolsDir.list()
        .findAll { it ==~ /[0-9.]+/ }
        .sort { a, b -> compareVersions(b, a) }
}
```

In my case, `System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME")` returned wrong path in `getAndroidSdkDir()` method, so the solutions are:

1. Simply replace `System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME")` with your real Android SDK path (but you should remember that SDK location differs on other PCs)
2. Setup correct path for `$ANDROID_HOME` environment variable
3. You can set build tool version manually in `build.gradle` files and skip calling methods described above (be sure to setup it for all the modules in the app):

   android {
       buildToolsVersion "your_version_here"
   }

Comment: Where is that file?

Comment: @Asmaa3107 you should use the Android SDK location path.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I fixed it by changing the Project structure as follows:

- Gradle version=3.5
- Android Plugin version=2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Start Android Studio.

On Android Studio landing page, select Configure > SDK Manager.

Go to tab **SDK tools**, you will see a warning regarding the build tools versions, just check to upgrade.